# Get buddypress group slug by passing its ID

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I would like to be able to get a link to a specific buddypress group but by only using the groups ID on a template page.

The admin inputs the groups ID as a custom field on the page, then using this I would like it to be able to generate the groups slug to then create a link to it

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a buddypress group slug from a group id:

```
$group_id = 2;    
$group = groups_get_group( array( 'group_id' => $group_id ) );
$slug = $group->slug;
```